# How can I parse out a line below a specific string?

Tags: bash, parsing

I am currently parsing a HTML document and I need to get specific data from it. Current example:

```
<div class="fifth price">
 80$   #I need to parse this whole line out            
</div>
```

There are more like this and I need to parse the prices out below every "fifth price" string.
How can I do it ? Thanks

Comment: Use `HTML`/`XML` aware tools like `xmllint`, https://linux.die.net/man/1/xmllint

Comment: It looks like what you really want is the text content of the `<div class="fifth price">`, which would make this a job for an HTML parser.

Comment: I see, but is there some kind of bash-only way ?

Comment: Am not sure what `bash` only way means, but any other tools are not reliable since they look for the pattern "as-is" and may not work in case the file is formatted flat instead of the standard new line format.